# Can't get JSONP to work with javascript from external file?

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

I'm trying to access some JSON data from an external file on a different server with JSONP and standard javascript but I can't get it to work. This is the script I'm using which is in a HTML page on a different server to the json file. Can anyone help please?

```
<script>

  function jsonCallback(data){
      console.dir(data);
  };

  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/v8xyYN64V4nqCshgjKms/data-2.json';
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

</script>
```

Comment: http://jsbin.com/yinowetugi/1/edit?html,js,output — It works when I test it. (Voting to close: Question must include enough information to reproduce the problem).

Comment: Thanks Quentin. Yes it does work in jsbin. I wonder if it is something to do with my server. Do you know how I access the individual data of the json file such as siteName, Domain etc?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**
There was a misunderstanding from me that I thought that the URL on the question is hosted by a server that the questioner owned. Let me leave my thoughts on the issue he is experiencing. So it is working in some environments, and not working in others. I tried to reproduce the issue, and I got "Reference: jsonCallback is not defined."

My testing environment was using Webpack to make a bundle out of my main script. And that bundle was modularizing my main script in IIFE way. So the function jsonCallback() was hidden out of the global scope, and that is why I got the reference issue. Also, I got the same issue when I tested it in jsfiddle, which was using iframe (Seperated scope). So to be clear, I put the main script directly in my index.html without passing by any compiling process, and it worked well, and jsonCallback() was invoked as expected.

As one of the comments below mentions, we do not have enough information to solve it. But I am leaving this information, hoping it to help the questioner by ANY chance.

---

JSONP is a very handy way to distribute your resources, avoiding CORS policy issue. However, it is ***NOT*** configured by default in many server frameworks.

I had the same issue when I was working ton Laravel 4.2. Let me share my work I did on the Laravel app so that you can get some idea how you can fix your server.

```
return Response::json('$response_body'); // Wrong
return Response::json('$response_body')->setCallback(Input::get('callback')); // Good
```

Also, It will be good to let us know which framework you are using for your server if you have a further question. Thanks.

Comment: There's a URL in the question. It returns JSONP. The problem is not the server. If you'd read the comments on the question, you'd see that the OP has acknowledged that there isn't a problem.

Comment: @Quentin where did you test it? If you tested it on Postman, and just assuming that it works fine. You are totally wrong. Test it on the browser, and you will see a JSON parsing error.

Comment: "where did you test it?" — I linked to a live demo in my comment on the question!

Comment: "Test it on the browser, and you will see a JSON parsing error" — JSONP is not JSON! If you try to parse it as JSON it won't work.

Comment: JSONP is a string that contains a javascript callback function. And it will be parsed into a javascript and will be called. Usually "jsonpCallback({...jsonObj})". Dude, take it easy. This is exactly the same issue that I got last time. The server frameworks do NOT support JSONP by default. If he wants to allow JSONP request to his server, then he needs to allow it in the sever side.

Comment: "And it will be parsed into a javascript and will be called" — Exactly. JavaScript. Not JSON.

Comment: "This is exactly the same issue that I got last time. The server frameworks do NOT support JSONP by default. If he wants to allow JSONP request to his server, then he needs to allow it in the sever side." — There is a URL in the code in the question. It returns a JavaScript program. That program conforms to the conventions of JSONP. The code in the question consumes it successfully. The link I put in my comment on the question goes to a live demo which demonstrates that.

Comment: Okay, but the response's header contains "Content-Type=application/json". And it should be "Content-Type=application/javascript". Check it in Postman. Do you still say that is not a server-side issue? I am pretty sure, the questioner will solve this issue very easily on the server side framework.

Comment: That might be an issue … but there is no way they will be able to edit the server side code on run.plnkr.co!

Comment: Then, the answer is run.plnkr.co doesn't support JSONP (properly).

Comment: Well, no, because as pointed out previously, nobody has been able to reproduce the problem. Which means it can't be answered.

Comment: @Quentin Okay. I reproduced the error. It's not a server-side issue. But Javascript scoping issue, if I am correct. So I tested it on my local server with Webpack. And Webpack was making my script as a IIFE module, which makes jsonCallback() function out of the global scope. He needs to expose the callback function to the global scope properly.

Comment: There is nothing in the question that suggests the OP is using WebPack. The code in the question clearly shows the callback is already a global.  A question needs a [mcve] which reproduces the problem. Answers can then solve that problem. A question which doesn't demonstrate a problem should be closed. It should not be answered with wild speculation about what the OP might have left out of the question.